# std::unordered_set return type by reference vs value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

Disclaimer: I am new to c++.

I have a code block like this:

```
  using BucketType = std::unordered_set<Bucket, BucketHash, BucketEqual>;

  const BucketType& Range::buckets(int64_t value) {
    BucketType buckets;
    ...
    return std::move(buckets);
  }
```

The caller calls this code like this:

```
  Range range;
  auto buckets = range.buckets(11);
```

Problem:

When I return the reference of the buckets like the code above, the `buckets.size()` gives `140732261909672` however, I am only adding 2 buckets in my actual logic. When I change the code to return value instead of reference, it works perfectly fine.

Any pointers on what might be wrong with this code?

Comment: Try removing the & from the return type of `buckets`.

Comment: Don't use `std::move` to return a value unless it's that rare case where it really is best. Not only will return values be moved out if possible, using `std::move` actually prevents the even better result of (N)RVO. Now this generally applies for by-value returns rather than by-reference. I'm not sure what your desired behaviour is for this return value.

Comment: Shorter version: Don't use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) unless you know what it does and how to use it.

Comment: And an even a shorter version: don't return references to objects in automatic scope. That's always a bug (unless the reference is never used, but in that case there's no point in returning it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider your `buckets` function:

```
const BucketType& Range::buckets(int64_t value) {
    BucketType buckets;
    ...
    return std::move(buckets);
}
```

Here you create a local object of the type `BucketType`, *move* it into the function's return value location, then return *const reference* bound to this **temporary** object. Undoubtedly, it leads to the *Undefined Behaviour*.

The right way to write such function is to simplify the code and get rid of `const BucketType&` and `std::move(buckets)`:

```
BucketType Range::buckets(int64_t value) {
    BucketType buckets;
    ...
    return buckets;
}
```

Now `buckets` becomes available for the *NRVO* (named return value optimization). It means that all the modern compilers perform *copy elision* here and construct `BucketType` objects directly (without creating temporary object in the function's return value location) when they are initialized with `buckets` function:

```
auto buckets = range.buckets(11); // No unnecessary copies here
```

Comment: If you drop the `const` the return object then the return cam be moved, if for whatever reason the copy can't be elided (impossible to guarantee elision without knowing what the `...` stand for.)

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, definitely!